# Who is "best with women" in Wheel of Time?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I have started reading The Wheel of Time series and no further than book two I 've read Rand, Perrin and Mat wishing they were as good with women as the other enough times to get my eyes rolling.

So I'd like people who finished the series to give me a definitive answer: Which one is best with women?

To keep this question from being POB I'd like the answer to be based on quantitative information: Who initiates more relationships during the series?

Comment: You're asking a POB question but then try to make it not POB by turning it into multiple, distinct questions, making it too broad. "And so on"  is a clue that you need to [edit] this with a more concrete, specific question.

Comment: @CreationEdge I wanted to add some dimensions to the question to make it more objective but I can see how it makes it too broad. I'll try to keep it simple

Comment: Is "more relationships" really the same as "better with women"?  They all have completely different approaches (and honestly, you're only on book 2; their love lives don't really take much shape until later in the series).  The important thing to notice here is that all three of them aren't confident in their skills with women.  It's similar to a commonly mentioned problem with facebook.  People don't share their insecurities, so everyone is prone to thinking those around them are less insecure than themselves.

Comment: none of them is as bad as they think they are, and none of them is as good as their friends think they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Who initiates more relationships during the series?

Mat.  Rand and Perrin don't initiate relationships.  They wait until prospective partners tell them they're dating.

Mat is the only one who initiates any relationships.  Although it's worth noting that his relationships tend to be of the one-night stand variety until women start initiating relationships with him.  Also, Mat's life has left his personality somewhat different from what it had been in the Two Rivers.

Rand does better (in quantity) than Perrin in that

> Rand ends up with multiple wives in the Aiel tradition.

But Mat is the only promiscuous one.

Of course, Perrin and Rand may have more sex than Mat.  Mat is constantly between partners until women start claiming him.  While Perrin and Rand have fewer partners, they are never between partners, just separated from them.

None of them ever have any particular success communicating with women.  Women communicate with them instead.  In rare cases they understand.  More commonly they find themselves asking some older male friend to explain things to them.  Mat might be best at this, but of course there are cultural differences with the woman that he is fated to marry.  His extra memories don't help him much with that.

Answer (score 2):

This topic was done many times, often hilariously, on Usenet's rec.arts.sf.written.robert-jordan ... you can look it up on Google Groups.

To show some of that here...

**Mat** is probably the guy you want here.  He's a flirt, a rake, and is into that whole "slap-and-tickle" bit.  Now his last two girlfriends kind of dented his reputation for suave Casanovahood, but hey.  He's doing a heck of a lot better than...

**Perrin**, who fits the standard Two Rivers pattern.  To wit ...

- Spend your youth bumbling around *almost* and *very nearly* asking girls out.
- Find one special girl whom you think is *way* out of your league
- Spend rest of your life being henpecked by her, and enjoy Every.  Damn.  Minute.  of it.  It's a Two Rivers thing.

**Rand** ... oh Rand.  He's such a mess.  He wanted to follow Two Rivers pattern like Perrin, but he's fated to have N simultaneous wives, where N is greater than one.  This makes him ... twitchy.